# Stack fails to install a package while reporting no error message

Tags: haskell-stack, nixos

When I try to install Haskell's [`scientific`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.3.5.1/docs/Data-Scientific.html) package using stack, it returns with no input as if `scientific` is already installed.

```
$ stack install scientific
$
```

and yet `scientific` is not installed.

Listing installed packages with `$ ghc-pkg list` returns no match.

```
$ ghc-pkg list | grep scientific
$
```

And furthermore, there is no directory on my entire system named `scientific`, as shown by the empty result of this find command.

```
$ find / -name scientific 2>/dev/null
$
```

**Why is `$ stack install scientific` failing to install `scientific`?**

I am using NixOS 17.03.

Comment: How about trying `stack exec -- ghc-pkg describe scientific`?  Stack installs libraries to package dbs that are not globally visible.  Within `stack exec`, it sets the GHC_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable, so that tools like ghc-pkg and ghc will see the package.

Comment: @mgsloan following your suggestion and using `stack exec` (e.g. `stack exec -- ghc-pkg list`) I *am* able to see an use `scientific`. For example, running `$ stack exec -- ghci` I am able to `import Data.Scientific`. Why doesn't stack just install to be 'globally visible', and how can I make `scientific` globally visible? I'd like to be able to just run `$ ghci` (without the `stack exec`) and have `scientific` be available as with my other packages.

Comment: If you're using `stack install` outside of a project, it installs the package globally for `stack`. It then should be available via `stack ghci`

Comment: @mherzl Stack sandboxes things by design.  For anything more than misc experiments, not having sandboxes quickly becomes untenable.  You can use "stack exec bash" to enter into a shell that allows you to run ghci straight.  Main crucial thing is having GHC_PACKAGE_PATH set.